# Windows 8 Desktop PC goes haywire after unlocking

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

My PC will lock itself after a period of not being used. After I input my password and unlock it, clicking shortcuts will either open the application multiple times or open the system 32 folder. Sometimes I can then click shortcuts, files or folders and other times I can't click anything at all. Pressing keys seems to either do nothing or open random applications and I can't access the windows 8 screen which shows my apps or bring up the side panel either once this has happened.

I've scanned my computer using Malwarebytes and Avast, found and deleted a few "potential threats" but am still having this problem. It only seems to happen after the computer locks itself.

Comment: Ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like trouble:
My suggestion is to refresh windows.

**Be aware that this deinstalls all your applications currently installed and can result in loss of data**

- Open the charm menu (windows + C)
- Click on 'Settings'
- Click on 'Change PC settings'
- Click on 'Update and Recovery'
- Click on 'Recovery'
- Click on 'Get started' button in 'Refresh your PC without affecting your files.'
- Follow the instructions on the screen.

**Be aware that this deinstalls all your applications currently installed and can result in loss of data**